# Should Subqueries always be select statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

```
select * from product where customer_id = (delete from product where product_id = 5 and customer_id = 1 returning customer_id);
```

When I run query above I am getting:

**ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"**

But running `delete from product where product_id = 5 and customer_id = 1 returning customer_id` separately is working fine and returning customer_id.

so question is does subquery always be select statement ?
Is there any other way to make delete and select in one query?

Comment: Should this not be: `... WHERE customer_id IN (delete ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
with d as (
      delete from product
      where product_id = 5 and customer_id = 1
      returning customer_id
     )
select p.*
from product p
where p.customer_id in (select d.customer_id from d);
```